# Non-admins can't create new entries with front-end form (ajax)

Tags: frontend-form

I'm hitting an issue where signed-in non-admin users can't create a new entry with a front-end entry form (but can edit existing ones). Everything works except for this single instance:

✓ Admin creates and edits entries from *non-ajax* front-end form (Works!)

✓ Admin creates and edits entries from *ajax* front-end form (Works!)

✓ Non-admin edits their entries from a front-end form (Works!)

**✗ Non-admin creates new entry from a front-end form** (Doesn't work)

Craft is returning: "**User is not permitted to perform this action**"

Tried all of these with and without CSRF on. This is the user group permissions on the section it's submitting to:

[image]

Using: Craft 3.1.21.1 (with multi-site)

*Edit: Original post stated that it was only a problem with ajax forms, but turns out it's all forms*

Comment: Could you include the response of your ajax request?

Comment: I have the same problem... Did you make any progress?

Comment: I solved my problem: I had to allow "edit site x" for the user group.